# Large Merchant Services for ebay in c#

Tags: ebay-lms

I'm attempting to send a file to the eBays LMS.

I have downloaded heaps of examples but they all have something missing.  Either they don't have all the references, or they don't tell me what packages to include.

Most often though they require something called a JobID, that I of course don't have because that's step one of the process.

So I'm wondering if anyone has seen or knows where to find a C# sample that contains all the bits.

Answer (score 2):

It took quite a bit of digging but I came to this. 
https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1338/related/1

It has an app that appears to do everything.  Though I've got a problem with it now, it is one of my making.

I am most happy.